# What happens in an APK Injection?

Tags: android, encryption, packet

I've seen a lot of online games be hacked via "APK Injections".  What exactly happens in an injection?  Are they intercepting the client-to-server packets and changing data on the fly or is it actual code being injected into the client (or server?) that runs a function?

If the injection itself is performing suspicious or unusual behaviour, how is it possible that those performing the injections aren't caught?

Comment: Seems like there's some information on this page: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+an+apk+injection&oq=what+is+apk+injection